# data modelling tools used by technology startups

Tags: data-modeling

I am familiar with data modelling tools used in enterprise software and IT organizations.

Want to know which data modelling tools are used by ***technology startups*** in particular, preferably with added info on - why.

Early stage and high growth startups, have different imperatives that influence engineering and development choices. Hence the question.

Comment: Most tech startups don't have a lot of money and many, if not most, of them are using Amazon or Google for the bulk of their cloud services, so I'd imagine most tech startups manage their data internally through AWS or GCP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a MySQL database, [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/en/products/workbench/) is a good tool (Opensource).

Otherwise you can use other data modelers as [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-data-modeler), [ERBuilder](https://soft-builder.com/en/erbuilder-data-modeler/) or [Dezign](https://www.datanamic.com/dezign) which support multiple RDBMS.
These three tools are easy to use.